# Is this sorting right? Or is it missing anything

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**This algorithm seems to work after a few tries but I'm not sure if it's right. Can anyone help?**

> n is the size of the array
>
> i goes from the first case to the case number (n-1)
>
> j goes from i+1 to n

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() { 
    int t[50];
    int i;
    int j;
    int n;
    int aux;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &t[i]);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) { 
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (t[i] > t[j]) {
                aux = t[i];
                t[i] = t[j];
                t[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("|| %d", t[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can indent it, it helps a lot

Comment: Hello :D I'm so sorry what do you mean lol?

Comment: please look up the meaning of indentation where you are studying, and apply it consistently. And also please don't use chat jargon like "lol"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in pseudocode, your algorithm is the following:

```
Sort(A, N):
  for (i = 1 to N-1):
    for (j = i+1 to N):
      if (A[i] > A[j]):
        swap(A, i, j)
```

where A is the array of numbers and N is the array size.

It's been a while since I tried proving the correctness of anything, but it seems that if the outer loop can guarantee that at the end of each iteration, the smallest number will be at `A[i]`, it will be correct. So the question is whether or not the inner loop puts the smallest element in `A[i]`.

Since it swaps `A[i]` with `A[j]` every time `A[i]` is larger than `A[j]`, we can guarantee that `A[k-1]` is always larger than `A[i]` at any `k`-th iteration of the inner loop, and therefore `A[i]` will be the smallest element for the subarray `A[i:N]` by the time the inner loop finishes executing (when `k = N+1`). Therefore, this algorithm is correct.

I am not too familiar with C programming so I can't tell you if your code exactly follows this, but if it does, then your code sample is also correct.